# Euler-Fermat theorem violating division algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Does Euler Fermat theorem not violates the division algorithm?E.g The remainder when 3^47 is divided by 23 is 27. Here remainder exceeds the divisor  that is violating the division  algorithm.

Comment: What makes you say that the remainder is $27$ ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust Since $\phi(23)=22$ and $47\equiv3\bmod 22$ OP is presumably using Fermta's little theorem to deduce $3^{47}\equiv 3^3\bmod 23$.

Comment: @arctictern I think Yves knows that but he is trying to get the OP to explain his reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

The remainder when $3^{47}$ is divided by $23$ is not $27$, it is $4$, and Fermat's little theorem does not say otherwise. You are presumably misinterpreting the meaning of the congruence $a\equiv b\bmod n$. This does **not** mean "the remainder when $a$ is divided by $n$ is $b$." That is not what it means. It is true that if $r$ is the remainder of $a$ dividied by $n$ then $a\equiv r\bmod n$, but the converse does not hold.

Instead, $a\equiv b\bmod n$ is equivalent to $a$ and $b$ having the *same* remainder upon division by $n$, or equivalently that $(a-b)$ is divisible by $n$. So for example, we can have $50\equiv27\bmod 23$ even though both of $50$ and $27$ are bigger than $23$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.